# Getting information from a USB activation program

Tags: .net, usb, reflector, cracking, autocad-plugin

My colleagues work with AutoCAD 2010 plugin called RCAD ( not sure if it is the correct name), but it works only on Windows XP installed on a Virtual Machine and It activates when they insert a specific usb.I need to develop the same pluggin in AutoCAD 2014 with the same functionalities of that pluggin but first i need to get information from the usb and the program.I couldn't find any dll or file inside the usb because all the files were hidden.How can i access the files or get some information from the usb? Can i crack the program with .NET reflector or something else? Any suggestion will help because i don't know here to start.Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You should start with observing what the tools do, take good notes and then recreate :)

How is the project coming?

If you hit any hard spots feel free to email me if you can't get an answer here. My email is in my profile here www.github.com/xxzer0xx

Comment: Ok thank you very much i will email you when i need help but now i'm on vacation :P